# How to pass store values in components

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I want to pass values in the store.state in components and got an error:
`[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined"`

So I called the value in the component directly and it doesn't work.

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
 state: {
    filter: {
      selected: false,
      value: 'test'
    }
  },
});

new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 template: `<div id="app"><div :selected="this.$store.state.filter.selected">Option</div></div>`
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.0.1/dist/vuex.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

> Vue

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
            filter: {
                value: 'test',
                selected: true
            }
        },
    mutations: {},
    actions: {},
    getters: {}
});
```

> HTML

```
<option :selected="store.state.filter.selected">{{store.state.filter.value}}</option>
```

Can I use it this way, or I need to think differently and how? Thanks.

> My current solution is store the value in computed variables, but would there be a way to pass Vuex store values into a component directly?

```js
computed: {
    filter () {
        return storeLogs.state.filter;
    }
}
```

```html
<option :selected="filter.selected">{{filter.value}}</option>
```

Comment: You can call store data with `this.$store.state.filter.selected`

Comment: When I changed it to `<option :selected="this.$store.state.filter.selected"></option>` it doesn't work. The error is **TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined**

Comment: You have to change both `{{this.$store.state.filter.value}}`

Comment: Still the same error

Comment: :/ Can you upload your project to codesandbox or can I check your code from teamviewer or else...

Comment: I've added a code snippet

Comment: Created a sandbox for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/1ykmw58ny7

Comment: Do you try `mapGetter` ? I dont think we get it from $store is a good way or delegate get data from store to component. It should state on Vuex module only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. You must pass your `store` object to the Vue constructor
2. There's no need to reference "this" in your template

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      filter: {
        selected: false,
        value: 'test'
      }
    },
});

new Vue({
    store, // add store object to Vue
    el: '#app',
    template: `<div id="app"><div selected="$store.state.filter.selected">Option</div></div>`
});
```

You can also use `mapState` like this in your .vue file:

```
<!-- MyComponent.vue -->
<template>
  <option :selected="filter.selected">{{filter.value}}</option>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex';
export default {
  name : 'MyComponent',
  computed() {
    ...mapState(['filter'])
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a very straight forward answer.